# How to tell if user exists

Tags: controller, services

I am automatically creating users in a service, is there a way to check if user exists?

I want to log in id user exist or save a new user if it doesn't, I have the following so far which will add a user:

```
public function add($user)
{
    craft()->users->saveUser($user);

    $user = craft()->users->getUserByUsernameOrEmail($username);
    craft()->userSession->loginByUserId($user->attributes['id']);   
}
```

Comment: Well, `craft()->users->getUserByUsernameOrEmail()` will return `NULL` if no users match the username or email address given – can't you just do a call to that method and check the return value before attempting to create a new user?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
public function add($user)
{
    $existingUser = craft()->users->getUserByUsernameOrEmail($user->username);

    if ($existingUser)
    {
        // They exist... log them in.
        craft()->userSession->loginByUserId($existingUser->id);  
    }
    else
    {
        // They don't exist... create them.
        craft()->users->saveUser($user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Except that you just redefined what 'user' is, and thus will be saving 'undefined' — I changed it to '$existingUser'.

Comment: That's what I get for answering before coffee.